# Weird working of correlated query - Is this SQL correct?

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

Please check the below query:

```
with sd as 
(
    select 1 id, 'abc' col from dual
    union
    select 2 id, 'xyz' col from dual
    union
    select 3 id, 'pqr' col from dual
),
t as 
(
    select 1 id, '123' col2 from dual
    union
    select 2 id, '233' col2 from dual
    union
    select 4 id, '456' col2 from dual
)
SELECT 
    id,
    col2,
    (SELECT 'ok' FROM dual WHERE SD_EXIST = 'Y') CHECK_CON
    --,SD_EXIST
FROM 
    (SELECT
         id,
         col2,
         CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sd WHERE sd.id = t.id)
                 THEN 'Y' 
                 ELSE NULL 
         END AS SD_EXIST
     FROM
         t) ;
```

There are 2 views defined - `sd` and `t`.

Final query inline view should return this result:

```
ID COL2 SD_EXIST
----------------
1   123   Y
2   233   Y
4   456   -
```

But the output of final query CHECK_CON column changes.

– if SD_EXIST is included in projection of select, CHECK_CON is null (for id 456) - Here the query behavior is working fine.

- if SD_EXIST is commented (not included in projection of select), CHECK_CON is OK (for id 456)- Here output is different and shows weird behavior of the query.

How does this work? I want understand the logic and working behind this and how it shows different results.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this either. Looks like a bug to me. https://dbfiddle.uk/jbQlUgii

Comment: there is something happening with the `from dual` subquery. If you change that to `case when SD_EXIST='Y' then 'ok' else null end CHECK_CON` the result is consistent.

Comment: Yes changing or rewriting it works fine, but not getting the root cause of this

Comment: Root cause in an Oracle bug.  If you replace the `WITH` statements with tables, for clarity, and do `DBMS_XPLAN`, you'll see Oracle isn't even reading from the `SD` table.  Similarly, if you use the `/*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION` hint, the results become correct.  Query transformations should never alter the result set of a query - in this case they do and that is prima facie evidence of an Oracle bug.

Comment: Yep, a bug. You can work around it by adding `/*+ NO_MERGE */`  in your inner block. Bugs are unfortunately not that uncommon. I've filed a half dozen of them in the past six months.

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner that this looks like an Oracle bug, likely related to some query optimization that is happening under the hood.  My best guess is the optimization changes when SD_EXIST is included in the select vs. not, which aligns to the execution plan output which is different when SD_EXIST is not included in the select then the plan seems to only include the UNION_ALL for t and not sd since it think sd isn't used. Example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/fJaaxVXV

Comment: I get that your goal here is to understand this query "as-is", but when I see such confused logic trying to produce a simple result, my knee-jerk reaction is to rewrite it.  Long experience has told me that Select statements inside column lists (what used to be called 'projections') are almost always an error.  Your simple results can be more efficiently and correctly produced by left joining 't' to 'sd' and comparing the two ids in a simple Case statement.